# Jersey Model Validation Exception: A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am extending an existing API class 'bar' with my own class 'foo'.

Here's how they are setup:

Class bar:

```
@Path("/bar")
@Produces("application/json")
public class Bar extends AbstractAPIClass {
```

Class foo:

```
@Path("foo/bars")
@Produces("application/json")
public class Foo extends Bar {
```

In each class there is an API, getBlah

Class Bar:

```
@GET
@Path("{blahId}")
@ApplicationApi
public Response getBlah(@PathParam("blahId") String blahId) throws IOException {
    Blah blah = blahService.getBlah(blahId);
    return new JsonResponse<>(Status.OK, "", blah).build();
}
```

Class Foo:

```
@GET
@Path("{blahId}")
@ApplicationApi
public Response getBlah(@PathParam("blahId") String blahId) throws IOException {
        return super.getBlah(blahId);
}
```

I get the following error on server startup:

> WARNING: A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP
> method GET and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and
> "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public
> javax.ws.rs.core.Response Foo.getBlah(java.lang.String,boolean) throws
> java.io.IOException and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response
> Bar.getNote(java.lang.String,boolean) throws java.io.IOException at
> matching regular expression /([^/]+). These two methods produces and
> consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as
> a resource methods will always fail.

We're utilizing an OSS application and need to inject security tokens/other values into every API call and we want to do that from our own API class so as to not touch too much of the OSS code. I am updating to a newer version of the OSS application and this error is new. We have things setup is identical to the old version and do not have this issue in the old version.

A google search tells me that the paths are the same, so the application cannot tell which API to use. But they aren't the same. One path is /bar the other is foo/bars and this works fine in with the old version of the OSS application.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Probably because you are extending Bar – its inserting the @Path, making them the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Paul. Are you suggesting that by extending Bar that Foo now has path /bar as well as foo/bars (or just /bar)? I guess that makes sense, it's odd though since these API classes are setup in exactly the same way as they were with the previous version of the OSS application and that worked fine. I'll see about not extending bar. Thanks again.